# Configuring an exception in web.xml security-constraint

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, web.xml, security-constraint

I know there are already other posts similar to my doubt, but the problem is that I could not solve the problem.
I have a servlet that must be mapped with the name "passport.jsp", because an external application (can not change the call) makes a request through a URL http://myipserver:portserver/nameApplication/passport.jsp?xxx
My web.xml in this point is here:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>PortalServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/passport.jsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The problem is that the mapping of my security-constraint overrides the definition of the servlet passport.jsp, because is mapping "*.jsp".

```
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>EsconderJSP</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>JSP</web-resource-name>
        <description/>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <description/>
        <role-name>jsps</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Does anyone know how to solve this? You can add the servlet "/passport.jsp" as an exception.

Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve just adding a new tag in my web.xml (other security-constraint)

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>free pages</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/passport.jsp</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
</security-constraint>
```

Ann it's working. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can add another security-constraint above it that has no protection

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <url-pattern>/passport.jsp</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>*</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Or you can change the application requests to start with something different to be protected.  This will leave the passport request unprotected.

```
http://myipserver:portserver/nameApplication/otherRequests/foobar.jsp

http://myipserver:portserver/nameApplication/passport.jsp
```

then only protect `/otherRequests/*`

```
<url-pattern>/otherRequests/*</url-pattern>
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your attention. I solve my problem with your tip. I put <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>free pages</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/passport.jsp</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
    </security-constraint>